# What is the query statement to write in order to solve the followin database problem?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following 3 tables in the database.

1. **Programs_Table**
   Program_ID (Primary Key)
   Start_Date
   End_Date
   IsCompleted
   IsGoalsMet
   Program_type_ID
2. **Programs_Type_Table**(different types of programs, supports a dropdown list in the form)
   Program_type_ID (Primary Key)
   Program_name
   Program_description
3. **Client_Program_Table**
   Client_ID (primary key)
   Program_ID (primary key)

What is the best way to find out how many clients are in a specific program (program type)?

Would the following SQL statement be the best way, or even plausible?

```
SELECT Client_ID FROM Client_Program_Table
INNER JOIN Programs_Table 
ON Client_Program_Table.Program_ID = Programs_Table.Program_ID
WHERE Programs_Table.Program_type_ID = "x"
```

where "x" is the Program_type_ID of the specific program we're interested in.

OR is the following a better way?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Program_ID FROM Programs_Table 
WHERE Program_type_ID = 'x'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$ProgramID = $row['Program_ID'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Client_Program_Table
WHERE Program_ID = '$ProgramID'");
mysql_num_rows($result) // returns how many rows of clients we pulled.
```

Thank you in advance, please excuse my inexperience and any mistakes that I've made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
<?php
// always initialize a variable
$number_of_clients = 0;

// escape the string which will go in an SQL query 
// to protect yourself from SQL injection
$program_type_id = mysql_real_escape_string('x');

// build a query, which will count how many clients 
// belong to that program and put the value on the temporary colum "num_clients"
$query =   "SELECT COUNT(*) `num_clients` FROM `Client_Program_Table` `cpt`
            INNER JOIN `Programs_Table` `pt`
            ON `cpt`.`Program_ID` = `pt`.`Program_ID`
            AND `pt`.`Program_type_ID` = '$program_type_id'";
// execute the query
$result = mysql_query($query);

// check if the query executed correctly 
// and returned at least a record
if(is_resource($result) && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    // turn the query result into an associative array
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    // get the value of the "num_clients" temporary created column
    // and typecast it to an intiger so you can always be safe to use it later on
    $number_of_clients = (int) $row['num_clients'];
} else{

    // query did not return a record, so we have no clients on that program
    $number_of_clients = 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: So is the AND used in the same way as the WHERE that I had used in the first query statement above?

Comment: @KyleL: The `AND` will force the `INNER JOIN` to match on both parameters. Yes, you can use the `WHERE` in this case as well, but it's much cleaner to use the `AND`. So, you can understand and debug it much easier, just by looking at them side by side.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how many clients are involved in a program, you'd rather want to use COUNT( * ). MySQL (with MyISAM) and SQL Server have a fast way to retrieve the total number of lines. Using a SELECT(*), then mysql_num_rows leads to unnecessary memory ressources and computing time. To me, this is the fastest, though not the "cleanest" way to write the query you want:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    Client_Program_Table
WHERE
    Program_ID IN
    (
        SELECT
             Program_ID
        FROM
             Programs_Table
        WHERE
             Program_type_ID = 'azerty'
    )
```

Why is that?

Using JOIN make queries more readable, but subqueries often prove to be computed faster.

Comment: Actually, subqueries are often A LOT slower than joins

Comment: I do not agree. The most explicit example I have is when you build a search engine, where subqueries (one level per keyword) can improve speed by factor 1000.

Answer (score 1):

This returns a count of the clients in a specific program type (x):

```
SELECT COUNT(cpt.Client_ID), cpt.Program_ID
FROM Client_Program_Table cpt
INNER JOIN Programs_Table pt ON cpt.Program_ID=pt.Program_ID
WHERE pt.Program_type_ID = "x"
GROUP BY cpt.Program_ID
```

Comment: I think he wants to retrieve the client knowing the value of **Program_type_ID**.

Comment: Ah, OK...the question said "What is the best way to find out how many clients are in a specific program?" But you're right, as I read down further they do specify Program_type_ID.  Good catch.

Comment: Do you need to do GROUP BY when you do INNER JOIN between two tables?

Comment: You need to do GROUP BY whenever you use an aggregate function in your query.

Comment: I agree, the question was wrongly asked and should be corrected.